# How does Go locate imported packages?

Tags: go

I am new to Go, and I have prepared my work space according to the [How to write go code](http://golang.org/doc/code.html)

But now I am confused how `go` tool gets the path of packages like `fmt`, `strings` or my own packages.

As in C language we provide the path of header file by `-I` and linker path by `-L` but in Go we have given two paths `GOHOME` and `GOPATH` and both paths are of bin directories none of them specify the package path.

Comment: "How to Write Go Code" shows exactly how GOPATH is laid out (this is actually what the first 3 sections aim to answer). Can you give a better example of what is confusing you?

Comment: i am c programmer and new to the concept of import My question is when we import any package ex. "fmt" package in our go code then how our go tool find where is the fmt.a file located??

Comment: The Go toolchain works by convention, the fact that you layout your code just like everyone else. You will almost never need to worry about where the object files live (their location is translated from the import path on demand), and they will get built as needed. Structure your source correctly, and everything else will follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is explained in the article you linked, `GOPATH` (and other go locations) should be layed out with a "pkg" directory for compiled libraries, and a "src" directory for library sources. They are not just bin directories.

Comment: note, you don't need to create the `pkg` and `src` directories. The go tooling does that for you.

Comment: If you're setting up a new `GOPATH` with a new project then you kind of need to create the `src` directory yourself, but it is true that `go get` will create whatever it needs in order to satisfy your request.

Comment: ohh So you are saying that where we have our src directory it fill find packages in pkg folder in same directory

Comment: @user2383973, ignore the pkg directory. You don't reference compiled object directly with the default Go tools.

Answer (score 0):

`$GOPATH` is a colon (or semicolon on Windows) separated list of paths to Go workspaces (with the {bin,pkg,src} structure). The go tools will automatically look for packages and source files in those paths when compiling and linking your programs.

Comment: On Windows, pathnames in `%GOPATH%` are separated with semicolons.